# Transfer money from my stripe account to my partners

Tags: laravel, stripe-payments, transfer

I'm new with using payment processors, I'm building a platform with **Laravel** to facilitate business between clients and manufacturers. First client pay for the job to be done and when the job is done we pay the manufacturers.
I'm using **Stripe** to charge clients and it works fine. However I'm stuck with the process of paying the manufacturers. because Stripe is not clear on how to do that.
please if you have a solution with or without stripe I'll be very grateful

Comment: This question does not have enough focus, show what you've tried and explain how it didn't work. Also I do not think Stripe is meant to be used as a clearing system, it's for processing incoming payments, not paying others.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like [Stripe Connect](https://stripe.com/connect) is what you're looking for. In this scenario, the client would be the platform account and the manufacturers would be the Connect accounts. Since you want the payment to the manufacturer to occur both after the job is done and after you pay the the client, you could use [Separate Charges and Transfers](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/charges-transfers).

Comment: thank you for replying, I did just that for the manufacturers I created accounts for them in Stripe Connect but I need to send the payment using the company stripe funds. Is that the way to go, or there is an easier alternative I could use

Comment: When you create a transfer (read above linked doc), the money is taken from the platform's Stripe account balance

Comment: yeah that's what I need exactly however I don't know what type of account should I create for the partners because they are international

Comment: There's some cross-border transfer restrictions. Just make sure you are all good there: https://stripe.com/docs/connect/account-capabilities#transfers